# orderby the last activity date

Tags: date, entries, orderby

I currently have a build in progress and am trying to achieve somthing that seems to be simple but is proving not quite so.

I would like to list say 50 entries, those 50 entries should be in a chronological order of either entry_date or last_comment_date. Using entry_date is fine for strict chronological but I'm also looking to see last_comment_date as well. If last_comment_date is newer then anothers entry_date then it should be higher up the tree.

Using `orderyby="most_recent_comment|entry_date"` yields most recent comments first then lists by entry date which isnt what is required.

I basically want to order by the last activity date - comment or entry. Is this approach possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Stash. Stash records each entry into a stash_list with an extra item that checks if there is at least one comment (if there is it must be newer then the entry_date) if there are no comments then the entry_date is the value.

Save the result of the if if:else as Unix Timestamp and then use stash:get_list and orderby the Unix Timestamp Var :)

```
{stash:activity_date}
{if comment_total > 0}{recent_comment_date format="U%"}{if:else}{entry_date format="%U"}{/if}
{/stash:activity_date}
```

Yet another reason to use Stash :)

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but the `edit_date` can be newer than the `recent_comment_date`. I suggest you to update your code.